# How to perform file logging in a multithreaded app

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging

I need a way of extreme fast logging (frame info about highspeed camera).
Its just a few numbers that I need to log, and a simple file.log.
Eventlogging is to slow for this.

So then I thought, well just create a file stream so i can lock the file for my app. and append to it.

Normally I would use a simple line such as

```
Filestream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Log.csv", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

inside a method.

However since the frames by the camera driver are executed each in a new thread I got a problem here. As I dont want to re-open and close the file each time the log file is written to. (open and close is slow).

I'd like to open the log file once, at the start of my program, and the threads should only perform a write to it, not closing and opening it again and again.

How to achieve this, since this doesn't work :

```
using System.IO;
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Log.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         // doing it in main doesn't work either.
         fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Log.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
       //...
       //.. init camera and start camera lots of code follows but is not related to the question.
     }

     Camera_Thread.FrameArrived (FrameArrivedEventArgs e)
    {   
       byte[] n = MyFilterFunction(e.frame);         
       fs.WriteByte(MyArrayToString(n));
    }
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is pretty unspecific. Please clarify what the actual problem is.

Comment: Why not use a [TextWriterTraceListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, i've tried several combination of declaring this file the compiler wont accept on how i try to declare it, ea the fs filestream variable is not recognized in camera_thread.FrameArived as fs isnt a global variable

Comment: I would use some logging library, like [nlog](http://nlog-project.org/) for this

Comment: FileStream is not thread safe. You should use lock statement to synchronize access to this resource. Also, fs.WriteByte(MyArrayToString(n)) looking suspicious, as WriteByte method accepts only byte type.

Comment: This has been solved in logging frameworks like NLog and Log4Net. Both support writing to disk asynchronously and support logging from multiple threads to a single file.

Comment: It seems `Camera_Thread` is the name of a class, for things you need to share between classes you need to store this somewhere both classes can access it. Since your question is still pretty vague about this, the best I can say is "that's not going to work", pretty much the same thing the compiler told you. You should consider using a logging framework though, as you have other problems, like locking and performance.

Comment: Why not use log4Net? It is very fast and thread safe too.

Comment: because its to slow for me

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of ways, but most if not all involve queueing, especially in a multithreaded environment.

You could use MSMQ to queue your logs for processing, you can also use a separate thread to process logs off an in-memory queue.

```
string logFile = "Log.txt";
this.Queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

var thread = new Thread(() => 
{
    string log;

    while (true)
    {
        while (!this.Queue.IsEmpty)
        {
            if (!this.Queue.TryDequeue(out log)) continue;

            File.AppendAllText(logFile, "\n" + log);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

});

thread.Start();
```

This implementation doesn't take into account how to cancel the logging thread, so I'll let you attempt that on your own first. I'll also add that this isn't very reliable, given the choice, I'd actually use MSMQ.

Comment: speed is really the issue i have, i need to log extreme fast.

Comment: Out of process queueing seems like a weird solution for an I/O problem to me. I think that would only make the problem bigger.

Comment: Sure, though you would then be risking losing all the logs stored in memory that were queued for processing, in the event that the app crashes

Comment: @MarnixvanValen well allready my program needs 8 CPU cores at 3.2Ghz to work, all code is paralized and optimized. There are not always easy answers to real world problems

Comment: Why don't you try the answer and then get back to us if you run in to issues

Comment: file.append opens, writes and then closes a file; i want top open a file only once perform highspeed logging, and on aplication exit close file.